# Do I need to store isUserSignIn for componet rendering in Local Storage(React,Next,Firebase Auth)

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, next.js

*(Firebase Google Signin + React(Next) )*

If user sign in , setState to true.
And render the home component and welcome(login) component in index.js by state value.I made an application by storing that state in local storage and I think it is not a good practice. So if I don't use local storage there is a issue when user signed in and it should reach the home component but , user can also see welcome component before home component.

***Logic*** index.js -> if userSignin (Home) : (Login)

**Conditional Rendering**

```
{isSignin ? (<>Home Component</>) : (<Welcome Component/>)}
```

**state**

```
const [isSignin, setisSignin] = useState(false);
```

**changing state if user signin**

```
useEffect(() => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {

    if (user) {
      setisSignin(true);
      console.log(user);
    }else {
      setisSignin(false);
    }

  });
}, []);
```

Comment: I don't think you will need to save isUserSignIn at the localStorage. because it will be a boolean state depending on whether the user is logged in or not

Comment: Yes Local storage do what I expect but I need something without using local storage for my component flickering You know , when user refresh the page , user can still see 2 second of login page because of react state. . I saw Next-Auth js and It is all what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firebase auto use localstorage when u signin an account. please check it in your browser localstorage. You don't need to store it by yourself. Then, when user revisit that website from the same web browser, firebase auto login (unless he did not logout). However, that auto login needs some amount of time. you need to do something during that amount of time. after that time, isSignIn will be true. I suggest something like this.

```
const [isSignIn, setSignIn] = useState(null);

useEffect(()=> listener_to_authstate_change() ,[])

if (isSignIn === null) return null; // something you like to show example - <Loading />

if (isSignIn === false) return <SignIn Component />

if (isSignIn === true) return <Home Component />
```

Comment: Firebase auto create user data in IndexDB. So Can I check that original IndexDB data for my component flickering issue instead of creating new localstorage boolean state. I also don't want to add loading.I want user experience like Next-Auth.js but I think they don't use firebase Auth

Comment: Loading is unevitable in websites, web-app and even mobile app. You can return null while checking user login or not. Or you can return placeholders. Check placeholder of bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/placeholders/

Comment: What if I don't want placeholder and loading state, do I need to do auth with server side ? This is just UI issues

Comment: I am not very familiar with Next js. What I knew is Nex js does not show blank page. It pre-renders possible pages, it has offline available, it render html first then javascript. For example, you have a page with login, signup and user data and others. Your page will load others first. During that load time, the page is not blank. But user cannot interact with login, signup, user data before Auth is downloaded.

Comment: If you used `<Link>User<Link/>` in `Home` page, `User` will be downloaded while user is in `Home` page. You can disabled that feature. Default is true. If user clicked to `User` page before `User` page is downloaded, `Home` page will not disappear yet. `Home` page will only disappear when `User` page is partially or fully loaded.